# Invalid character in a Base 64 string

Tags: c#

I get the error 'Invalid character in a Base 64 string' in this code:

```cs
private void Decryptstring(string inputstring)
{
    MessageBox.Show(inputstring);
    byte[] inputByteArray = new byte[inputstring.Length + 1];
    UnicodeEncoding UE = new UnicodeEncoding();
    byte[] key = UE.GetBytes(password);
    RijndaelManaged RMCrypto = new RijndaelManaged();

    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms,
        RMCrypto.CreateDecryptor(key, key), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
    // this Probleme =>
    inputByteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(inputstring);
    cs.Write(inputByteArray, 0, inputByteArray.Length);
    cs.FlushFinalBlock();
    Encoding encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

    MessageBox.Show(encoding.GetString(ms.ToArray()));
}
```

Comment: `inputstring` isn't a valid Base64 string.

Comment: we need to see `inputstring`, but it sounds like : it isn't valid base-64

Comment: Can you please edit your question so that the title is in english ? i think the problem is that your 'inputstring' contains characters that are not valid for a base64-string

Comment: this inputstring:`n:����곰������xS�ӗz��@���E���8j�^��+�������@���)J� �*��|ç��0��pC�̧d���o#Ve<���,Bɛ��&3��KE�/d#u��{�;��^9*ܧ��Z���_��W�6��CC%��� ��E�V�~tΞ�%n/��$��H��:A��J�
�S+:��Q�4��
�)gJ��;<�ER8��J�ؤe�p�nIW������a�+TBw]��`f-)^oD�rf�:L����X/'5�~@(��d������[�i��X.,�u����f�ȏ���ftpa/��sgc@Y�OE�,-c��l��-��
�."��������DȎ�@H���)V���3���
�Tq�B
$E��W�Ej'N��q�UBU+k�,O��y��aW�����Q
D��-¿�M��L���:g�|�@;�k�Ad
�_��w�f�<j��l�&w$o�a�v�Q
BC��¯9�-����������?l��a�ٵ���ȃe��ϵg*C���';�
ik�x���[VM��)�!������c0�u��_LȻ�t�H�I3�-M0�$%
����f`

Comment: @nure yeah, that isn't base-64; so; is it *meant* to be? if you're meant to be receiving base-64, then the sender is wrong and needs fixing; if you're incorrectly *assuming* you're meant to be getting base-64, then: update: you're not - so find out what you're *actually* getting; for comparison, base-64 looks like: `aGVsbG8gd29ybGQ=` - it is a 6-bit encoding of arbitrary bytes using 64 commonly printable alphanumeric (etc) ASCII characters (plus some for alignment)

Comment: `public static bool StringIsBase64(string myString)
{
   Span<byte> buffer = new Span<byte>(new byte[myString.Length]);
   return Convert.TryFromBase64String(myString, buffer , out int bytesParsed);
}` try this helper function before doing anything with the string.